# using wpdb to insert into SQL SERVER database with PhP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, wordpress

I am attempting to convert a php form script I created from an external MySql database to an external SQL server database. I have properly copied the database over and just seem to be having a problem getting the form to use the WPDB object to use insert into the new SQL server database. The same creation script was used for both databases.

The insert statement:

```
try {
$externalDB->insert('EmployeeApp.dbo.applicant', array(
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name,
            'middle_name' => $middle_name,
            'suffix' => $suffix,
            'nick_name' => $nick_name,
            'email' => $email,
            'idnumber' => $idnumber,
            'street_address' => $street_address,
            'city' => $city,
            'state' => $state,
            'zip' => $zip,
            'phone' => $phone,
            'ged' => $ged,
            'over_18' => $over_18,
            'previous_app' => $previous_app,
            'previous_app_date' =>$previous_app_date,
            'previous_emp' => $previous_emp,
            'previous_emp_date' => $previous_emp_date,
            'us_citizen' => $us_citizen,
            'visa' => $visa,
            'us_eligible' => $us_eligible,
            'date_avail' => $date_avail,
            'name_change' => $name_change,
            'name_change_info' => $name_change_info,
            'discharged' => $discharged,
            'military' => $military,
            'military_info' => $military_info,
            'high_school_name' => $high_school_name,
            'high_school_city' => $high_school_city,
            'high_school_state' => $high_school_state,
            'highest_grade_completed' => $highest_grade_completed,
            'additional_skills' => $additional_skills,
            'convicted'=> $convicted,
            'convicted_name' => $convicted_name,
            'convicted_date' => $convicted_date,
            'convicted_charge' => $convicted_charge,
            'convicted_sentence' => $convicted_sentence,
        ));
        $lastid = $externalDB->insert_id;
```

The database connection object:

```
try{
$externalDB = new wpdb(EMP_DB_USER,EMP_DB_PASS, EMP_DB_NAME, EMP_DB_HOST);
}catch(Exception $e){
echo $e->getmessage();
}
```

`$wpdb` has been declared as a global at the top of the script and this was working perfectly before I connected to a SQL server database. 
I am wondering if I need to not use `$externalDB->insert()` with SQL or try a different table call such as just 'dbo.applicant' or just 'applicant'. Not sure about the transition and can’t find a lot of documentation on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [look at the code](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1504), you will see that the `wpdb` class connects only to MySQL databases. This is an [acknowledged limitation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Alternative_Databases#Database_Challenges) of Wordpress, and although there have been [some attempts by third parties](https://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami) to rectify the situation, nothing official has happened yet!

Comment: Ahh thank you, There was some confusion about this due to a couple of post on here stating that it would connect to ANY database. Is it possible to write a pure php connection and parameterized queries to use on a wordpress site? I am using it as a custom template as a work around and just creating the page under that template name.